# explode and select each element from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

I have a small task where I have a mysql table "shops".It contains a column "categories". Each field of categories contains diiferent values like "22,44,33,55,24,33,22"
Now taking each value from that field, i need to get the value from a column "parent" in another table. (linking with ids) I am selecting the whole string, but i want to select each number. Please help me with this.

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("",$con);
$sql = "SELECT categories from shops";
$array = mysql_query($sql,$con);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($array)){
foreach($row as $value){
    $result= explode(" ", $value);
    foreach($result as $newvalue){
    $query="SELECT parent FROM categories where categories.id=$newvalue<br/>";
    echo $query;
    }
    }
    }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: And this is why you normalize your database with a separate `shops_categories` table to record that relationship instead of stuffing comma-separated numbers into the same field.

Comment: im sorry,i cant normalize my database but need a solution for it...

Comment: check MySQL function [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Is `22,44,33,55,24,33,22` a data in a field in a single row and data in multiple rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exploding based on a space  charater but your value needs to be exploded on the basis of `,`. So try that

```
$result= explode(",", $value);
foreach($result as $newvalue){

    $query="SELECT parent FROM categories where categories.id='$newvalue'";
                                                           // ^ Quotes the Value
                                                           // Remove the <br />

    echo $query."<br />"; //Instead add it here and avoid the bug if you decide the run the query

    // This example is showing mysql_* library but it is deprecated

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $parent = $row['parent']; //Now you can something like this


}
```

Comment: @user1694724, Added an example

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given...got an error

Comment: @user1694724, Can you update the question with what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If your categories column contains "22,44,33,55,24,33,22" then surely your explode should be

```
$result= explode(",", $value);
```

eg explode on the comma in the string to give you 22, 44, 33 ...

Comment: If you updated your code with the change we all suggested, you should see it print out your queries as you asked..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here `$result= explode(" ", $value);`
It should be `$result= explode(",", $value);`

Comment: make another query using the values extracted from $result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result= explode(",", $value);
```

Since the format of the string is separated by comma, should explode the string by comma instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are the values separated by commas?

Even though your problem is a database design, `explode(',', $value)` should get you the IDs.

Comment: Well, you already have the categories ids that that category is related to, with that id you could query the same table, but, as I said, a better table design must be a better approach.